# How to determine width and height of outer rectangle when it is scalled to an inner rectangle

Tags: geometry, functions

I have a rectangle with more than 800 width and 600 height. It can be 1000 x 600, 2000 x 1000 and etc. I want to scale it to 800 x 600. I want to determine which one matches first, the height or the width and also get the other value that didn't meet first.

```
|                |
|  |800x600   |  |
|  |inners rec|  |
|                |outer rectangle(1000 x 1000) if I resize which one will hit the boundaries of the inner rectangle left and right or top and bottom.
```

updated

I used the term square When it should be rectangle.

Comment: Look at the ratios of width to width or height to height.  Pick the larger or smaller one, depending on your numerator and denominator.

Comment: Your comment ins an answer in its own right: "Look at the ratios of width to width or height to height. Pick the larger or smaller one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the ratio in each axis and use the smaller one.  So if you start with $2000 \times 1000$ the horizontal is $\frac {800}{2000}=0.4$, the vertial is $\frac {600}{1000}=0.6$.  So you scale by a factor $0.4$ and the vertical is $0.4 \cdot 1000=400$.  These are rectangles, not squares.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! \o/. Great answer!